# Passaport-Local-Mongoose: How do i allow identical usernames

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I'm using Passport Local Mongoose to create a user on my database. My goal is to allow users with the same username to register into my app. On my research, i found that if i pass an object as option on my Schema.plugin with 'usernameUnique: false', i would allowed users to register with the same username. The only problem is when a try it to make a register, i get an "UserExistsError" on my console.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: false
    },
});

const options = {
    usernameUnique: false,
}

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, options);
const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Comment: It sounds like the lookup function is checking for a user by username, so you'd have to either remove that check or check based on a different set of criteria. Why do you want to allow multiple users with the same username though? From a system design perspective that's inadvisable.

Comment: I didn't realize that the passport uses the username field to login each user. In my mind, to login, I would use EMAIL and password to log the user into the application (which I already took precautions not to let the same emails register).

Comment: It looks like `passport-local-mongoose` requires `username` to be one of the unique lookup fields so usernames will have to be unique. Passport auth is based around `username and password` as opposed to `email and password`. There are other js auth libraries that allow `email and password` though...